# How do i update the players leaderstats in a script, what is connected to a proximity prompt in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to know how to change the player who activated the proximity prompt's `leaderstat` in Roblox but it isn't working.

This is my script

```
script.Parent.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(Player)
    if Player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Card") or Player.Character:FindFirstChild("Card") then
        --how do update my leaderstats--
       else
        print("You must be a crm for this")
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a parameter for the player who triggered the Proximity Promt, `Player`, you can access their leaderstats simply by doing `Player.leaderstats`. This is because when you make the leaderstats folder, you set it to be a child of the player. You can then edit any leaderstat value, for example: `Player.leaderstats.Money.Value += 1000`

Answer (score 0):

The player's leaderstats object is in the player itself so you can access it by `Player.leaderstats`. If the value is a string value then `Player.leaderstats["Value"].Value = "Hello World"` or if the value is an int or num value then `Player.leaderstats["Value"].Value = 123`

Comment: While you have the right idea, just remember that the leaderstats inside a player is a `folder`, so in order to change values inside the leaderstats, you would have to access the value *inside* the leaderstats: `player.leaderstats.<Leaderstat Value>.Value`